# Failure when trying to delete service key of s3 storage service

Tags: swisscomdev

Deleting a service key fails with internal server error.

The following command produces the error:

```
cf dsk -f storage storage-keys

Deleting key storage-keys for service instance storage as user...

FAILED

Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker failed to delete service binding for instance storage: Service broker error: Internal Server Error
```

The error seems to be specific to this service key. It is a service key of a S3 storage service. I tried for several days with always the same error result. Withing the same time span deleting othe service keys (of Maria DB services) worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Swisscom specific problem that we have experienced as well. The only way to resolve the error was to send a direct support request via this form:

https://developer.swisscom.com/support

They will then proceed to manually delete the binding and ideally fix the related server error.